# How to read a variable from another folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

im just confused in one part. I dont know how to make a global variable so i can use it on another file. What i have now is a chat and a login folder. And in the login folder you can be either three people as i listed. So automatically when the user clicks the button of either three( whitch is the three people), i want the chatt app to know who it is, so i have to make a variable where i get the data of who is it and transfer it to my chat folder somehow. And i dont know how to do that. Please help thankyou. And im currently using Ang Js.

This is the Login Page:

[image]

And this is a seperate folder. Now when he clicks submit i will redirect it to the chatt folder using angular js but i dont know how to take if he is one of the users with me so automatically when i chat i know who it is.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question or the description of what it is you are trying to do...

Comment: Oh ok @NewToJS what is happening is second ima take a screen shot and edit the problem so its more understandble

Comment: There are three people chating over one browser window? And you want to transfer a chat into the chat-folder? I would expect something like a chat server which takes care about the chat.

Comment: @NewToJS i editde problem

Comment: You mean you want to have a variable that is global for 2 different html pages or the same page (app)?

Comment: @JohnDoe so which one? two different pages?

Comment: You can use localStorage to save username in one page and read it in the other.

Answer (score 0):

The global scope maps to window so you should be able to do:

```
window.user = 'user 1'
```

and then access it from your other js files.